# PivotCache Refresh - Cell formula return #Value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2003

I have a pivot table created from external data source(access) that contain number of records for each hour on a weekly basis for an average period of 3 months. Just beside this pivot table, I've created a column that calculates the average number record for each hour for a day. (A week here is just 5 days - sat & sun don't count).

To achieve the above, I have created a UDF that counts the number of weeks from the pivot data field (Week_Ending). To ensure the code don't count ghost or non-existent weeks, I have used the pivotcache refresh in the UDF. This works perfectly, except it now gives #value (A value used in the formula is the wrong data type) in the cells where I expect the daily average. I have found no issue with the cell formula and works if a single week is selected from the field "Week_Ending" instead of ALL.

I have attached the code and cell function and an image of the issue.

[image: Screen Capture #value error]

Cells formula in Cell E6 and it is similar upto cell E29 (Hourly cell reference is incremented by 1 for each cell)

```
=IF($E$4=1,GETPIVOTDATA("CountOfCase_Id",$A$4,"HOURLY",A6)/5,GETPIVOTDATA("CountOfCase_Id",$A$4,"HOURLY",A6)/($E$4*5))
```

Vba UDF function

```
Option Explicit

Function WeekCount(InputVal As Variant) As Integer
Dim book1 As String, PivotName As String

    book1 = ThisWorkbook.Name

    With Workbooks(book1).ActiveSheet
        If InputVal = "(All)" Then
            PivotName = .PivotTables(1).Name
            .PivotTables(PivotName).PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone
            .PivotTables(PivotName).PivotCache.Refresh
            WeekCount = .PivotTables(PivotName).PivotFields("WEEK_ENDING").PivotItems.Count

        Else
            WeekCount = 1
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

I appreciate any help. Excel version is 2003.

Comment: Yes, the UDF is invoked from cell `E4 (=WeekCount(B2))`.  If the formula as per your suggestion is copied down, the results are displayed. However, if change Week_Ending to a single week and back to ALL, then the same #Value error is displayed. My existing cell formula works if you manually input 13 or select a single week (UDF input 1 in cell E6).

Comment: WEEK_ENDING contain only date and time - `10/02/2013  12:00:00 AM`. However, the UDF does not do much except count the number of items when _ALL_ items are selected in the field Week_Ending. The issue started when I added code for Pivotcache refresh.

Comment: Yes, that did it. I put your suggested approach in place and it works like a charm. I used the `refreshtable` code and left out the `update` code. Update code bring back the same issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be with

> .PivotTables(PivotName).PivotCache.Refresh

in the UDF and not fixed with `Application.Volatile`. However @GSerg’s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70947/how-can-i-refresh-all-the-pivot-tables-in-my-excel-workbook-with-a-macro) without `p.update` seems to have worked.