# Excel VBA/button to refresh two or more pivots simultaneously

Tags: vba, excel

In another post I was provided with the following VBA code to attach to a "Refresh" button to refresh Pivot data:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Button5_Click()

Dim PvtTbl                  As PivotTable
Dim PvtCache                As PivotCache
Dim PvtDataRng              As Range

' Set/Update Pivot Data Range
Set PvtDataRng = Worksheets("PivotDataSheet").Range("A1:E100") ' <-- just an example

' Create/Update Pivot Cache
Set PvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(xlDatabase, PvtDataRng)

' Set the Pivot Table (already created, otherwise need to create it)
Set PvtTbl = Worksheets("DD").PivotTables("test")

' refresh the Pivot Table with the latest Pivot Cache
With PvtTbl
    .ChangePivotCache PvtCache
    .RefreshTable
End With

End Sub
```

How can this code be modified to simultaneously refresh a 2nd pivot in the same worksheet? Lets call this 2nd pivot "test2" and it is also in the DD worksheet.

Thanks,
Kevbo

Comment: Just repeat the steps of the code you've been given with the other pivot table name...

Comment: Does the second pivot table named "test2" has the same source of data as the first Pivot Table ?

Comment: Are both pivot tables based on the same data source?

Comment: Yes they are using the same data source. Wont adding a duplicate of this code overwrite the definition of Set PvtTbl =?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you have only these 2 `PivotTable` in "DD" worksheet, and you want to update these 2 based on the same `PivotCache`, then replace the following `For` loop :

```
With PvtTbl
    .ChangePivotCache PvtCache
    .RefreshTable
End With
```

With the following `For` loop:

```
' refresh all Pivot Tables in "DD" worksheet
For Each PvtTbl In Worksheets("DD").PivotTables
    With PvtTbl
        .ChangePivotCache PvtCache
        .RefreshTable
    End With
Next PvtTbl
```

---

**Edit 1**:  `Set` the `PivotCache` inside the `For` loop, and clear it at the end. use the loop below, and remove the `Set PvtCache` line from it's previous place.

```
' refresh all Pivot Tables in "DD" worksheet
For Each PvtTbl In Worksheets("DD").PivotTables
    ' Create/Update Pivot Cache
    Set PvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(xlDatabase, PvtDataRng)

    With PvtTbl
        .ChangePivotCache PvtCache
        .RefreshTable
    End With

    Set PvtCache = Nothing ' <-- clear the Pivot Cache
Next PvtTbl
```

Comment: Almost there...

Received runtime Error 5: "Invalid Procure call or argument" on the line:
'.ChangePivotCache PvtCache'

Comment: @Kevbo did it fail on the first `PivotTable` ? or the second ?

Comment: Looks like the 2nd, because the first refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this myself but you could try and tell me if it works. It seems like it may work for you

```
Function refreshPTcontent()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pi As PivotItem

On Error Resume Next
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
       For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
         pt.RefreshTable
       Next pt
    Next ws

End Function
```

Comment: Not sure if I used it correctly, but I added that code to existing macro. It didnt refresh the 2nd pivot.

Comment: Sorry about that, I wasn't sure if it was gonna work. 
try with `ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll` this might be slow tho.
Source: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/9/27/vba-guide-excel-pivot-tables

Comment: Check this one too...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70947/how-can-i-refresh-all-the-pivot-tables-in-my-excel-workbook-with-a-macro